# Defining elastic/flexible structure in C

Tags: c, structure

I have a task to do and the content of the task is:

*Please suggest a definition of linked list, which will keep the person's name and age in a **flexible structure**. Then write the procedure for inserting elements with the given name and age.*

What exactly is a flexible structure? How to define it? And then how to malloc the size?

```
typedef struct Test {
int age; // ?
char name[?]; // ?
struct Test * next;
}Structure;

int main(void) {
Structure *one = malloc(???);
}
```

Comment: _What exactly is a flexible structure?_ Perhaps it will be a linked list.

Answer (score 4):

You are on the right track. However, there is no "flexible structure". You want to use a **flexible array member** (avail since C99) in a `struct`:

```
typedef struct {
    int age;
    size_t name_size;    // size of the array, not length of the name!
    char name[];         // Flexible array member
} Structure;

int main(void) {
    Structure *one = malloc(sizeof(*one) + SIZE_OF_NAME_ARRAY);
}
```

Note I added a name_size field. C does not store the size of allocated arrays, so you might need this for safe copy/compare, etc. (prevent buffer overflows).

Using `*one` makes this term independent of the actual type used. The size of such a struct is as if the arrray had zero elements. However, it will be properly aligned, so it can differ from the same `struct` without the array.

Also note that you have to change the allocated size if you use other than a `char` array to something like `sizeof(element_type) * ARRAY_SIZE`. This is not necessary for `char`s, as their size is defined by the standard to be `1`.

Comment: Do I have to put name_size in struct? Instead of it can I just do it by e.g. #define SIZE 81 ?

Comment: @Karmel: As I stated in my note: you certainly do no need to. It just comes in hand to always have it available with your **flexible** array, so you do not need to pass it to every function which **might** need this information. Using a constant also works, of course, but what would be the point of using a **flexible** array member instead of one with a constant (i.e. `name[SIZE]) size?

Comment: @JensGustedt: Thanks! At first I really didn't know what you mean. Feel free to edit if you like. I'll check the edits anyway later to learn from my mistakes/typos.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Reading your profile where you welcome feedback: is there a chat room or the like to take that offer?

Answer (score 1):

my guess: a flexible struct would be one that could handle any age and any name.

A `unsigned int` field would handle any age (within reason).

A `char *` field would handle any name.

The struct itself would be:

```
struct nameAge { unsigned int age;  char * pName; };
```

an instance of the struct would be:

```
struct nameAge myNameAge;
```

Setting the `age` field would be:

```
myNameAge.age = ageValue;
```

Setting the `name` field would be:

```
myNameAge.name = malloc( numCharactersInName+1 );
strcpy( myNameAge.name, nameString );
```

How the code obtained the ageValue for age and/or the characters for NameString is up to the programmer to decide/implement.

Comment: Ok, sorry, that sounds a bit like a joke (no offence(!!), just made me smile): "... would handle any age". Ok, it depends on which age to store. If that is for (known) living species, don't you think a `signed short` would still be more than sufficient already? (For astronomical ages, even an `uint32_t` would be too small, otoh).